# File / URL authorization failed for the SECOND request

Tags: asp.net, iis, authorization, windows-authentication

I have an issue similar to these:

[URL authorization failed for the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914332/url-authorization-failed-for-the-request)

[IIS File authorization failed for the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752000/iis-file-authorization-failed-for-the-request)

I am running several similar web sites on IIS 7.  I am testing with Firefox, so that I can act as users other than me.

I have been doing all my work on site 1.  I can log in as network users `administrator` and `sys\bob`.

I am now working on sites 2 and 3.  I can log in as `administrator` just fine.  The problem is:  When I log in as `dom\bob`, the initial log in is properly authenticated.  On all subsequent requests, `dom\bob` is rejected for either a file or a URL authentication failure.

The Application event log entries are materially similar to those quoted in the linked issues, except that the custom event details section is empty.

I have checked the web sites in IIS Manager and found no differences so far.  I have confirmed that the `web.config` files are identical, except for site-specific information such as the connection string.  I have verified that the folder permissions are correct as far as I have looked.

Specifically on permissions:

The `<authentication>` mode is `Windows` on all web sites.

The `<authorization>` node in particular is identical between web sites.

The local domain is the same MS Windows Server 2008 virtual machine in all cases -- one server image hosting multiple web sites.  So in theory, user authorizations should be identical across all web sites.

--Edit 1--
Just my luck.  I had this authorization issue pop up on web site 1, on a JavaScript file that has run just fine before, during a sprint review.  There was the twist that in this case, the user was able to go through quite a few pages before the authorization failed.

I'll post my logs as soon as I can.

--Edit 2--
I did make one environment change shortly before this issue started:  I updated jQuery and Bootstrap.

Here's my diffs in `packages.config`:

**Before**

```
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**After**

```
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap" version="3.3.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

And here are two typical entries in the Application event log, appropriately sanitized.

1:

```
Event code: 4008 
Event message: File authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 6/2/2016 2:31:29 PM 
Event time (UTC): 6/2/2016 6:31:29 PM 
Event ID: e4a0fd65d9e34686967f14429d21ab97 
Event sequence: 14 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/21/ROOT-1-131093658656731243 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HAWK_WebForms\HAWK.Web.LogansRun\ 
    Machine name: BAH01 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5288 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: HAWK\administrator 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:53104/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js 
    Request path: /Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js 
    User host address: ::1 
    User: HAT\john.smith
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: NTLM 
    Thread account name: HAWK\administrator 

Custom event details:
```

2:

```
Event code: 4008 
Event message: File authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 6/2/2016 2:28:51 PM 
Event time (UTC): 6/2/2016 6:28:51 PM 
Event ID: a43d7292a8894df193600e829e74c696 
Event sequence: 14 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/14/ROOT-1-131093657141125131 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HAWK_WebForms\HAWK.Web.LogansRun\ 
    Machine name: BAH01 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5248 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: HAWK\administrator 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:53752/Scripts/Pages/Admin/SelfRatingWizard.js 
    Request path: /Scripts/Pages/Admin/SelfRatingWizard.js 
    User host address: ::1 
    User: HAWK\james.jones
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: NTLM 
    Thread account name: HAWK\administrator 

Custom event details:
```

--Edit 3--

I tried adding the registry key from this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13015279/2615836

It didn't change anything.  I also double checked the order of the authentication providers.  NTLM is already ahead of Negotiate for all the sites.

--another update--
I rolled back Bootstrap and jQuery.  To my astonishment, the file authorization still fails!  Again, `jQuery.js` is one spot -- just about every file raises this complaint.  It's as if the authorization token gets "forgotten".

--update to Edit 1--
The JavaScript file that was raising issues in web site 1 did not have permissions for `Network Service` like all the other JavaScript files did.  Once I fixed that, web site 1 was resolved.  Alas, this fix did not resolve web site 2.

Comment: I have run `iisreset` and rebooted the VM.  Neither attempt resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that the directory for Project1 gave read permissions to the domain group Users, and none of the other projects did.  Once I granted Users the Read permission on Project2's base directory, the authentication issue was resolved.

So it was an OS-level user permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may occur (in different browsers) when several factors are actual at the same time:

- The WindowsAuthentication is enabled. The AnonymousAuthentication is disabled;
- The server is accessed by the IP address (not by the alias);
- A first ajax request is completed;
- 1 minute timeout is lapsed.

Check the [ajax request hangs when referring to server by IP address and WindowsAuthentication is enabled in IE11](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1093357/) thread regarding this.

Check if this issue is applicable in your case. If so, try using any other value from the above list to (temporarily) overcome this problem.

Comment: I'm accessing the server by the URL, not IP address.  Specifically: `localhost:53104/Hawk.aspx`.  `Anonymous Authentication` is enabled and set to Application pool identity; `Windows Authentication` is enabled and accepting Extended mode authentication.  I don't think there are any AJAX requests that happen during page load.  And I'm not using IE.  So I don't think that's the issue.